# Run web application from zip file on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

More then I thinking, more I am asking my self what am I missing.

Let's say that I have an (ASP.NET) application. All files in folder are read-only. Why I could not just pack it with uncompressed zip or tar and show it to "Add Application" process in IIS?

Performance vise I don't see any problem. Or even it could be faster, because there is no security checks, but just plain data. Deploy would be more consistent and quicker, specially if you have thousands of files. And this would be specially cool, if you could run application package with new dotnet like `dotnet run MyApplicationPackage.zip`.

Normally I found on web for any my idea a lot of articles, but not on this one.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking or looking for in an answer.  how is an "uncompressed zip file" any different than just dropping a folder in a location?  Why would there be no security check, what do you mean just plain data?  I'm not sure how deployment would be any faster, because either way it's a single file/folder that is moved.

Comment: One of my web applications has more then 10. mostly small files. In sense of speed copying it over network it is a lot longer if there would be in single uncompressed file.  By security check I was thinking on file system security. So, if you need to check security policy for 1 file I believe it could be faster then for 10k files. I am asking this because I already use one system where 10k of files are combined in one file and because of this handling data (in sense of files) is much easier and faster.Would be easier if build server could prepare only one file and this would be enough for IIS?

Comment: Docker is a more standard way to do so. ZIP is not an ideal format.

Comment: Even docker is not ideal, far from it :) Well, maybe windows containters are direction in this idea, but my is a lot simpler.

Comment: dropping a folder in a location vs creating a zip file ***while making sure to select the uncompressed option***.  Doesn't really seems simpler to me :/

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to distribute application for IIS in form of ZIP/TAR/WAR files.

This sounds more like premature optimization, as you say you have 10 files.

Comment: No, I said 10k files (10.000 files).